# Code::Blocks error multiple definition of 'main'

Tags: c++, c++14, codeblocks

i tried to install my first program but it doesnt run. As the default program runs correctly. I created the new file as File>new>empty file and saved as .cpp but the program doesnt run. Ive matched the program from the book and the default one..
What is wrong

Comment: Please provide more information on the error, and the code written to cause the error.

Answer (score 1):

you can only have one main. By removing the Untitled.cpp file you will only have one file, main.cpp. you  give your new file  a name instead of taking the default name "Untitled.cpp". Or you can simply create an new project